# How to accelerate downloads using Cocoa API

Tags: cocoa, download

I'm working on a simple download manager wrote in Cocoa and actually I use `NSURLDownload` to do the trick. The problem is that I guess `NSURLDownload` download the file from only one segment and I know that other download managers download files for many segments in order to improve download performance.

In fact, I think I have to split the file I want to download into multiple segments and simultaneously downloads all these segments.

The problem is that I don't know how to do it. I already search a lot in the internet without any success.

---

Edit : Here is a working solution thanks nacho4d help:

```
NSURL *downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.urltodownload.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 1000.0];
int fromByte = 0;
int toByte = 1000;
NSString *range = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bytes=%i-%i", fromByte, toByte];
[request setValue:range forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
[[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact answer for this but if you see at this [Java example](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/how-to-create-a-download-manager-in-java.html), you will see you can add a "Range" property in the HTTPConnection object to select the part to download:

```
// Specify what portion of file to download.
connection.setRequestProperty("Range",
        "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
```

I think that is a hint and maybe there is a place in the `NSURLRequest` or `NSURLConnection`, etc to put this "Range" property :)

Assuming that is possible, I think you will need to make simultaneous n connections and put everything together when all connections are finished.

If you find the exact answer I would be glad to know too :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In fact, it's possible to specify the range in a NSMutableURLRequest object. Here is a small example : `NSURL *downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.urltodownload.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 1000.0];
int fromByte = 0;
int toByte = 1000;
NSString *range = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bytes=%i-%i", fromByte, toByte];
[request setValue:range forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
[[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];`

Comment: It's working now. Thank you. I have another question for you, what do you think is the best way to write in a file with n thread in the same times ?

Comment: There are several options here, the simplest would be: use a for loop to start all NSURLDownloads and when all delegates say they've finished you put together all the parts together using NSData. (There should be a best way of putting everything together I think :).